# Searching for a partial match in a list of tuples

Tags: python

If we have a list of tuples:

```
[(0,1),(1,2),(5,5),(4,1)]
```

How can I find all items which partially match a search term?

Eg, in the above example, `(_, 1)` should match `(0, 1)` and `(4, 1)`.

Comment: if you have two questions, it is best to make two separate questions for them. just to make the site more organised.

Answer (score 5):

You can implement wild-card matching by using a special object that always compares as equal to any other object. Eg

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Any:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Any'

ANY = Any()

#Test
if 1:
    print ANY
    for v in [1,2,'a', 'b', (2,3,4), None]:
        print v, v == ANY
    print

def match(target, data):
    ''' Check that sequence data matches sequence target '''
    return len(data) == len(target) and all(u==v for u, v in zip(target, data))

data_list = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (5, 5), (4, 1)]
target = (ANY, 1)
print [v for v in data_list if match(target, v)]
```

**output**

```
Any
1 True
2 True
a True
b True
(2, 3, 4) True
None True

[(0, 1), (4, 1)]
```

Here's a better version with a fancier `Any` class, thanks to [Antti Haapala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918959/antti-haapala). It prints the same output as the code above.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class AnyBase(type):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Any'

    @classmethod
    def __subclasscheck__(cls, other):
        return True

    @classmethod
    def __instancecheck__(cls, other):
        return True

class Any(object):
    __metaclass__ = AnyBase

    def __init__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("How'd you instantiate Any?")


#Test
if 1:
    print Any
    for v in [1,2,'a', 'b', (2,3,4), None]:
        print v, v == Any
    print

def match(target, data):
    ''' Check that sequence data matches sequence target '''
    return len(data) == len(target) and all(u==v for u, v in zip(target, data))

data_list = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (5, 5), (4, 1)]
target = (Any, 1)
print [v for v in data_list if match(target, v)]
```

To use the first version we really should create an instance of the class, but the `Any` class in the second version is designed to be used directly. Also, the second version shows how to handle `isinstance` & `subclass` checks; depending on context you may wish to restrict those tests.

Comment: Today you have one in the std libs: `from unittest.mock import ANY`

Comment: @wim Thanks for that info.

Answer (score 4):

```
new_list = [i for i in old_list if i[1] == 1]
```