# RDD.sortByKey using a function in python?

Tags: python, scala, sorting, apache-spark

Lets say my key is not a simple data type but a class, and I need to sort the keys by using a comparison function. In Scala, I can do this by using, `new Ordering`. How can I achieve the same functionality in Python? For example, what would be the equivalent code in Python?

```
implicit val someClassOrdering = new Ordering[SomeClass] {
        override def compare(a: SomeClass, b: SomeClass) = a.compare(b)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, you can create class methods for comparison by using the [rich comparison methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__):
`__lt__`, `__le__`, `__eq__`, `__ne__`, `__gt__`, `__ge__`

You can make these methods do anything you need to compare your class instances, even weird things, but it's a good idea to make them consistent if you want sorting to behave sensibly. :)

Here's a fairly simple example of their use in this answer I wrote a month or so ago: [Sort a list to form the largest possible number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30141885/4014959).

Here's another cute example from [Searching for a partial match in a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867270/4014959), which creates a wildcard object.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `keyfunc` argument:

```
from numpy.random import seed, randint
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])

seed(1)
rdd = sc.parallelize(
    (Point(randint(10), randint(10)), randint(100)) for _ in range(5))
```

Now, lets say you want to sort Points by y coordinate:

```
rdd.sortByKey(keyfunc=lambda p: p.y).collect()
```

and result is:

```
[(Point(x=5, y=0), 16),
 (Point(x=9, y=2), 20),
 (Point(x=5, y=2), 84),
 (Point(x=1, y=7), 6),
 (Point(x=5, y=8), 9)]
```

Comment: That is really cool. Will try that. Here you just use a member field of the class, but let us say I want to use a class method for comparison, how would I do that?

Comment: One option is to implement rich comparison methods as mentioned by @PM2Ring. If your logic is not covered by any of these operator you can simply call a method `sortByKey(keyfunc=lambda x.some_method())`

Comment: @MetallicPriest: In Python 2 you could also implement a magic `__cmp__` method, but that's deprecated & no longer exists in Python 3.

Comment: It's worth to mention that some basic Python types like `tuple` or `list` are sorted lexicographically by default.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you may use `key` argument of `sort()` method. There was also `cmp` function, but this solution wasn't optimal and is now deprecated (or even removed, depending of Python version). Take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).