# Python - String search

Tags: python, string

Lets suppose I have these two strings:

```
IAMASTRIPETHA-IWANTTOIGN-RE

IAMA-TRIPETHATIWA-TTOIGNORE
```

If in this case I would ignore the positions of the '-', those two strings are the same. How can I accomplish this in Python 2.7?

```
IAMASTRIPETHA-IWANTTOIGN-RE

IAMA-TRIPETHATIWA-TTOALGORE
```

The above example is not similar when ignoring the '-'; hence I don't care.

Hope someone can help me out ;)

**PS: Apologies for not mentioning this but it is not required for strings to have an equal length!**

Comment: `str1.replace('-','') == str2.replace('-','')`

Comment: @MarounMaroun thats not what OP wants

Comment: @vks Are you sure? That's what I understood.. please correct me if I didn't get him.

Comment: @MarounMaroun try to run it and see.

Comment: Now I got you.. thanks.

Comment: Find all positions of `-` in both strings and remove all of those positions from both strings; then compare the result. That's rather trivial, please at least attempt to implement it yourself before asking SO to do your work for you.

Comment: Please do also mention what you want to return if the strings are of unequal lengths .

Comment: Hi Anand - Doesn't really matter for me. I only care if a string is contained within another string when ignoring these -'s. Solution worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = "IAMASTRIPETHA-IWANTTOIGN-RE"
b = "IAMA-TRIPETHATIWA-TTOIGNORE"

all(x==y or x=="-" or y=="-" for x, y in zip(a, b))
>> True
```

Comment: This answer is nice and pythonic

Comment: @AnandSKumar Well seen. I added a condition on the string length to fix that.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Your interpretation is what's wrong. There is nothing in the problem specification that states the strings have to be the same length in order to be considered a match. Only that corresponding non-hyphen characters are the same.

Comment: @machineyearing Well in non same length strings , you would consider them similar if the length till the shorted string is matching? If so, you interpretation is wrong.

Comment: It's not about what *I* would consider, or what *you* would consider. Read the problem, give an answer to the problem, and don't inject your own requirements into the specification based on what you think the problem *should* be.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I'm going to see if it works in my more complicated cases. I indeed don't mind whether the strings are from different lengths.

Comment: "similar" is an English word and there's no general-purpose mathematical semantics for it

Comment: Yes, but given that its not clear from the requirements what needs to be done for cases where the strings are not of equal length, it is better to give a solution that works for both cases, than one that only works for one case. Especially since its not that hard to come up with a solution that works for both cases (Not at all hard) . And he has already given that solution, so not sure what you are getting so worked up over.

Comment: There is literally no solution that works for both cases, since in one case you would have to return `False` if the strings are different lengths, but in the other you would return `True` if the prefixes match. Either way it doesn't make this answer "wrong", which was your original comment that I disagreed with.

Comment: @Koen: Since you don't mind that the strings are of different lengths you _really_ should have mentioned that in your question. It's not too late to edit it in now, but just do it in such a way that future readers will know that you didn't mention it originally.

Answer (score 1):

It appears from the comments that you don't care if the string lengths don't match, so we don't need to test lengths, and we can use the built-in `zip()` rather than importing `zip_longest()`.

```
s1 = 'IAMASTRIPETHA-IWANTTOIGN-RE'
s2 = 'IAMA-TRIPETHATIWA-TTOIGNORE'
s3 = 'IAMA-TRIPETHATIWA-TTOALGORE'

def ignore_dash_match(s1, s2):
    return all(c1 == c2 for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2) if c1 != '-' and c2 != '-')

print ignore_dash_match(s1, s2), ignore_dash_match(s1, s3)
```

**output**

```
True False
```

---

Here's an alternative approach which converts each `'-'` to a "wildcard" object that compares equal to anything.

```
s1 = 'IAMASTRIPETHA-IWANTTOIGN-RE'
s2 = 'IAMA-TRIPETHATIWA-TTOIGNORE'
s3 = 'IAMA-TRIPETHATIWA-TTOALGORE'

class Any:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

def dash_to_Any(s):
    return [Any() if c == '-' else c for c in s]

print dash_to_Any(s1) == dash_to_Any(s2), dash_to_Any(s1) == dash_to_Any(s3)
```

**output**

```
True False
```

You could make that slightly more efficient by using a single instance of Any, rather than creating a fresh one every time. But for a better version of Any please see my answer to [Searching for a partial match in a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867270/4014959).

And of course if you don't care about mismatched lengths you can do

```
def ignore_dash_match(s1, s2):
    return all(c1 == c2 for c1, c2 in zip(dash_to_Any(s1), dash_to_Any(s2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't write for you a full solution, but will guide you.

You need to get the indexes of the "-" in both strings, and replace by the empty string in each correspondingly.

In order to find the positions of "-" in a given string, you can have:

```
get_indexes(st):
     return [m.start() for m in re.finditer('-', st)]
```

Now you should replace these indexes in the other string by the empty string, and compare them.

This solution is robust and doesn't assume anything about length.

Comment: I guess it's robust, but it does take an extra pass over each string. And IME regex tends to be slower than the built-in `str` methods for simple tasks like this.