# Getting more control over the rich comparison operators in python2

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
>>> class Yeah(object):
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return True
...     
>>> class Nah(object):
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return False
...     
>>> y = Yeah()
>>> n = Nah()
>>> y == n
True
>>> n == y
False
```

The left guy wins because when python2 sees `x == y` it tries `x.__eq__(y)` first.

Is there any way to modify `Nah` so that he will win both times?

My use-case is making something like this:

```
class EqualsAnyDatetime(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, datetime)
```

It just works in python3 because `real_datetime.__eq__(random_other_thing)` raises `NotImplemented`, giving the other side a shot at the comparison.  In python2 I can't seem to get the idea working.

Comment: Realistically, equality should be symmetric.

Comment: Of course it should.  That's why I want `any_datetime = EqualsAnyDatetime()` to work on both sides, not just the left side.

Comment: @wim Do you require `__eq__` in `Nah`, if not then removing that from the `Nah` will invoke the function in `Yeah` for both `y == n` and `n == y`

Comment: Imagine you could do this by somehow specifying `Nah` as "preemptive" (so it gets first shot at the comparison).  Now what do you think should happen if you do `Nah == Other` or `Other == Nah`, where `Other` is another object that also identifies itself as "preemptive".  No matter what you do, there has to be a rule about what to do first.  If you let objects say "me first", then you'll just have the same problem when two objects say "me first" at the same time.

Comment: I would answer to have `Nah`'s `__eq__` to call `Yeah`'s, but I am afraid to be donwvoted. I have tried and it works, but maybe I haven't grasped the essence/constraints of the problem

Comment: @BrenBarn I had considered that. If both sides have implemented the "me first" feature, it is acceptable for the left side to win.

Comment: Although it doesn't solve your problem, you might like to take a look at my Any wildcard object in the last codeblock of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29867270/4014959).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way that can give the right hand side the opportunity to say "me first".  The trick is to inherit from the type(s) who you want to strong-arm the comparison against.

Example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> class EqualsAnyDatetime(datetime):
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return isinstance(other, datetime)
...     
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> any_datetime = EqualsAnyDatetime(1970, 1, 1)
>>> now == any_datetime
True
>>> any_datetime == now
True
>>> now.__eq__(any_datetime)
False
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that.  The left-hand operand is always tried first.  If it handles the operation, the right-hand operand never gets a chance to do anything.